# Highlight the active collection button in shopify

Tags: shopify

I have a list of a collection I am calling in Shopify. I tried to use the `link active` tag but its not working. Here is my snippet

```
{% for collection in collections %}
  {% unless collection.handle == 'frontpage' %}
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info {% if link.active %}class='active'{% endif %}">{{ collection.title | escape | link_to: collection.url }}</button>
  {% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
```

I am trying to add `active class` to the active collection, or the collection URL I am on presently.

I don't know what I am missing here.

Comment: what is `link.active` here and where is it coming from?

Comment: @HymnZ

I am trying to add `active class` to the active collection, or the collection URL I am on presently.

Comment: `link.active` will work only inside a linklist loop/object . I don’t see any linklist object here.

Comment: If link.active won't work. What will work, any idea?

Comment: Where are you adding this code? Can you validate it using collection.handle . Also, don’t use a reserved variable like **collection** in custom loops.

Comment: I am using the code in collection.liquid.

I don't understand this part
 Also, don’t use a reserved variable like collection in custom loops.

can you explain a bit more

Comment: Check my answer. And please spend sometime understanding Shopify “objects” from their documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, your code will function erratically. `collection` is a reserved variable in Shopify and by using the same variable in the loop, you might be changing the actual collection altogether. And secondly, link.active will only work inside a linklists loop.

Here's what you can do: change the assigning variable for the unit in your loop and validate if the handles are the same.

```
{% for thisCollection in collections %}
  {% unless thisCollection.handle == 'frontpage' %}
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info {% if thisCollection.handle == collection.handle %}class='active'{% endif %}">{{ thisCollection.title | escape | link_to: thisCollection.url }}</button>
  {% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
```